# Get projects by tag with Gitlab API

Tags: gitlab

I've noticed that the Gitlab API doesn't seem to have a method for filtering projects based on tags like the "explore" section does. I was having a bit more trouble finding the implementation of the Projects.search() method to see if it allowed for this.